# What is the probability that four shoppers who each visit one of four malls visit exactly three of them?

Tags: probability

Assume four shoppers visit four different shopping malls. Each shopper picks only one mall, and no shopper knows the choices of the other shoppers. What is the probability that exactly three malls are chosen?

I think that there are $256$ ($4 \times 4 \times 4 \times 4$) different allotments, given that some malls can get multiple shoppers while others none at all. For the exactly three I was thinking of the binomial theorem but haven't been able to set it up.

Comment: What have you tried so far ?

Comment: I'm not as good a mathematician as the vast majority of people on this site, but I think that there are 256 (4x4x4x4) different allotments, given that some malls can get multiple shoppers while others none at all. For the exactly three I was thinking of the binomial theorem but haven't been able to set it up.

Answer (score 2):

So as you noticed there are $4^4$ of total outcomes; what remains is to find the number of favorable outcomes, that is the outcomes when exactly 3 malls are visited. Let's use counting principle:

- choose the mall that is not visited; there are $n_1$ ways.
- among the remaining 3 malls, choose the mall visited by 2 people; there are $n_2$ ways;
- choose two persons among 4 that visit the same mall; there are $n_3$ ways;
- among the remaining 2 persons and two malls, choose the mall visited by the 1st person; there are $n_4$ ways;

Finally, the answer is
$$\frac{n_1n_2n_3n_4}{4^4}$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

If $A_i$ is the event that exactly i mall is chosen then you are asking to calculate

$\frac{N(A_3)}{N(A_1\cup A_2\cup A_3\cup A_4)}$

where $N(A_i)$ is the cardinal number of $A_i$.

For example in order to calculate $N(A_3)$ you should think that there is a mall with exactly two shoppers and the other two malls with one each but also that there are different malls that this should happen. This results to

$N(A_3)={4\choose 2}{2\choose 1}{2\choose 1}3!$.